# "Branching"/"Forking" a framework repo that you own?

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I'm working on a game engine / framework. It functions like Laravel in that you work within the original directory structure (mainly in dedicated "App" folder).

I would like to be able to use this framework in such a way where if the original were to update, I can pull the changes, similar to a branch. However this is a separate project created theoretically by other users, so it must be in a different repo.

How can I do this with git?

Comment: It's trivial with Git: there's nothing special about any clone. Just clone any clone and you have another clone. It's less trivial with GitHub which layers their "fork" on top of clone: you only get *one* fork. That's a GitHub thing; you have to handle that on the GitHub side.

Answer (score 1):

> I can pull the changes, similar to a branch

Since you cannot fork your own repository, you can simply:

- clone it
- rename origin to upstream (to keep a reference to the original repository)
  `git remote rename origin upstream`
- add the URL of a new empty repository and push everything
  `git remote add origin https://url/new/empty/repo`
  `git push --all`

At any point, you can `git fetch upstream` and merge for instance `upstream/master` to your own branch in your second repo.